# Compilation error with c

Tags: c, makefile

I am trying to compile a program called randfold which deals with RNA folding. However during `sudo make` , I am getting the following messages for c programs.

```
params.o: In function `scale_parameters':
params.c:(.text+0x160): undefined reference to `log'
params.c:(.text+0x1bc): undefined reference to `log'
fold.o: In function `HairpinE':
fold.c:(.text+0x3981): undefined reference to `log'
fold.o: In function `LoopEnergy':
fold.c:(.text+0x3bd3): undefined reference to `log'
fold.c:(.text+0x3dfa): undefined reference to `log'
fold.o:fold.c:(.text+0x4f81): more undefined references to `log' follow
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [randfold] Error 1
```

What could be the reason for these errors?

Comment: Please don't do `sudo make`! Just `make`! It doesn't make any sense at all to run the build as `root`, and it can be very risky.

Comment: @jongware yes it probably is. I couldn't find it and there were so many questions on this forum that I found it easier to just ask the question. I will be more careful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `-lm` at the end of your compilation (linker) line to link with the math library.

Comment: you mean **sudo make -lm**

Comment: @RahulUnnikrishnan no, edit your Makefile to add `-lm`